# Summing Values in Visible Rows Only

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with one group of which the visibility is toggled based on if the [total] is greater than 5. I want to make another row, that adds up only the visible information from each column. The first column is the owner name, The 3rd column [total] gets divided by the second column to get the 4th [avg] column. Right now it's counting everything, including the hidden rows.

Also, columns 2-4 are calculated based on expressions

Example of what I want it to look like

```
Owner    Count  Total   AVG

Bob      3      12      4
Jane     1      9       9
Marcos   2      24     12

TOTAL:   6      45     7.5
```

I also need to count the visible Owners total, and divide that by the total amount of active owners, which I pull from a second dataset.

Example if we had 12 owners total

```
Total listed owners: 3
% of owners: 25%
```

Answer (score 1):

For the total displayed owners, just `SUM` on the expression you use to hide the row:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Total.Value > 5, 1, 0))
```

then to get the percent, divide this by the `COUNT` of the total rows, including the hidden ones (which you already have).

Comment: I'm still having an issue. I'm not sure why it's not working but I have this exactly:
        =Sum(IIf(Count(Fields!Group.Value)\CountDistinct(Fields!cmp_code.Value) >= 5, 1, 0))
It shows up as 0 every time.

Comment: If that is exactly what you have, it is not going to work because you are using a backslash \ rather than a forward slash / to do the division

Comment: I'm getting the same results with the slash in either direction.